# Record libglut rendering?

Tags: glut

I've created a small "particle system" at 
https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/particleman.c 
(compile with "gcc -lglut particleman.c -o particleman"), and now want 
to record the output. How do I do this?

I tried using recordmydesktop, but it didn't work well, and inherently 
seems like the wrong tool.

Can I get libglut to output an MP4 file directly?

If not, can I get it to output each frame as an image (and then use 
other software to combine those images)?

This seems like it should be easy, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glReadPixels` to read the pixels of the framebuffer to an array. Aftwards you need to store the data in an image file - here some code:

```
rectangle<int> rect = getViewport();

const int width     = rect.width;
const int height    = rect.height;

const size_t bytesPerPixel = 3; // RGB
const size_t imageSizeInBytes = bytesPerPixel * size_t(width) * size_t(height);

// Allocate data for pixels
uint8_t* pixels = new uint8_t[imageSizeInBytes];

glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

// save data to an image
Image img(width, height, pixels);
buw::saveImage(filename, img);
```

glut cannot ouptput a MP4 directly.